# What is the correct context area for bpy.ops.uv.snap_selected?

Tags: python, scripting, operator

I'm trying to execute the command `bpy.ops.uv.snap_selected(target='PIXELS')` in Blender Python, but i keep getting that context is incorrect.

I've run the following Python script in order to find the correct context

```
import bpy

#all the area types except 'EMPTY' from https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Area.html?highlight=area%20type#bpy.types.Area.type
types = {'VIEW_3D', 'IMAGE_EDITOR','NODE_EDITOR','SEQUENCE_EDITOR','CLIP_EDITOR','DOPESHEET_EDITOR','GRAPH_EDITOR','NLA_EDITOR','TEXT_EDITOR','CONSOLE','INFO','TOPBAR','STATUSBAR','OUTLINER','PROPERTIES','FILE_BROWSER','PREFERENCES'}

#save the current area
area = bpy.context.area.type

#try each type
for type in types:
    #set the context
    bpy.context.area.type = type

    #print out context where operator works
    if bpy.ops.uv.snap_selected.poll():
        print(type)

#leave the context where it was
bpy.context.area.type = area
```

But I'm getting nothing printed. I've tested this with the operator `bpy.ops.uv.pack_islands` for example and I'm getting results.

Why I'm getting no valid area type for `bpy.ops.uv.snap_selected`? Is it a special operator? Can it be run from Python code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you have to modify not only the area type but also the `ui_type` for this to work. For the specific case of `bpy.ops.uv.snap_selected` operator, the `area_type` is `IMAGE_EDITOR` and the `ui_type` is `UV`. This piece of code works:

```
bpy.context.area.type = 'IMAGE_EDITOR'
bpy.context.area.ui_type = 'UV'
bpy.ops.uv.snap_selected(target='PIXELS')
```